# $scope don't work on $http.post

Tags: php, angularjs

I have a problem with my script, when I want insert data to mysql. 
Everything works fine but $scope don't send data to post.config.

Here is the code of controller:

```
    app.controller("addNewsCtrl", function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.postData = function($scope) {
        $http.post("php_libs/add_news.php", {
          'newstitle':$scope.newstitle,
          'today':$scope.today,
          'content':$scope.content
        }).then(function(response) {
          console.log(response.statusText);
        });
      };
});
```

And code from template:

```
<div>
  <form>
    <div class="form-group">
      <?php $today = date("d-m-Y"); ?>
      <label>Tytuł:</label>
      <input type="text" ng-model="newstitle" placeholder="Wpisz tytuł" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Data:</label>
      <input type="date" ng-model="today" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Treść: </label>
      <textarea ng-model="content" placeholder="Wpisz treść posta..." class="form-control"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" ng-click="postData()">Dodaj post</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

When I was use console.log(response.data) that give me "undefined"

Now my controller look this:

```
app.controller("addNewsCtrl", function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.postData = function() {
    $http.post("php_libs/add_news.php", {
      'newstitle': $scope.newstitle,
      'today': $scope.today,
      'content': $scope.content
    }).then(function(response) {
      console.log(response.data);
    });
  }
});
```

But console.log still return nothing.

PHP code

```
flag    

<?php include("connect.php"); 
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input")); 
$title = mysql_real_escape_string($data->title); $date = mysql_real_escape_string($data->post_date); 
$text = mysql_real_escape_string($data->post_text); 
$sql = "INSERT INTO news (title, post_date, post_text) VALUES ('" . $title . "', '" . $date . "', '" . $text . "')"; 
$res = $conn->query($sql); ?>
```

Data send in chrome dev tools https://s30.postimg.org/mkcf7dfb5/Bez_tytu_u.png

**The actual error is a php error **

Comment: Try removing `$scope`  in the post function unless you are passing it explicitly -  `$scope.postData = function() {.....`

Comment: Do you have more php code in your file or is this all?

Comment: it's all that i using for this task.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the parameter `$scope` from your method becuase `ng-click="postData()"` won't pass scope as the first argument. So it'll be undefined in `postData` method's local context:

```
$scope.postData = function() {
    $http.post("php_libs/add_news.php", {
      'newstitle':$scope.newstitle,
      'today':$scope.today,
      'content':$scope.content
    }).then(function(response) {
      console.log(response.statusText);
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `$scope` from `postData()` function .

or pass `this` keyword to the function in your ng-click, like 
`ng-click="postData(this)"`

Comment: I try. Thats the same effect.

Comment: You mean $scope is still undefined?

Comment: Now $scope have no values. In console is empty row.

Comment: Everyone. Still empty row in console. $scope didn't send data and in database i have empty records :)

Comment: put scope on console and let me know if $scope is empty or not?

Comment: That's return me this: https://s29.postimg.org/b22trjflj/Bez_tytu_u.png

Comment: I didn't get it

Answer (score 0):

You have implemented Post function in Controller and $scope is an object with the available properties and methods of controller. So, you have already scope of the controller in your post function and you do not need to pass it as parameter.

Your code needs to be like this.

```
    app.controller("addNewsCtrl", function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.postData = function() {
        $http.post("php_libs/add_news.php", {
          'newstitle':$scope.newstitle,
          'today':$scope.today,
          'content':$scope.content
        }).then(function(response) {
          console.log(response.statusText);
        });
      };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this!

All problems was by **mysql_real_escape_string();**

This works perfect:

```
<?php
  include("connect.php");
  $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));

  $title = $data->postTitle;
  $date = $data->postDate;
  $content = $data->postContent;

  $sql = "INSERT INTO news (post_date, post_title, post_content) VALUES ('$date', '$title', '$content')";

  $res = $conn->query($sql);

?>
```